# Make code inside ajax response persistent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX call in my code like this:

```
      var resultatAJAX = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,            
        success: function(data) {            

        }
      });              

      resultatAJAX.success(function(data) {               
        if (data == "false") {
          info_estancia[0]['foto'] = "null";
        }
      });
```

This call executes a php script that checks if the url parameter of the call exists or not. works fine. What I try to do below is to modify a value existent outside the ajax call depending if the response is true or false.

Problem is that the changes I do inside the success funcion dont take effect: after the success funcion I check the value of "info_estancia[0]['foto']" and it keeps unmodified.

Is there any way to make the code inside the success funcion to persist or in other way get the response of the ajax call outside the function itsetf ?? Something similar to:

```
      var resultatAJAX = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,            
        success: function(data) {            

        }
      });
```

where resultatAJAX got the True/False response.

**EDIT**

Finally it works, dont ask me how but setting some console.logs I supose that something changed and all was fixed.

My question now is: Do I need the resultAJAX.success to make the changes persistent or doing the same inside the success of the ajax call woudl work aswell ?? Is better to set the call async then ?? if not, my coude would keep runnging and maybe the value of the "info_estancia[0]['foto']" would not be the desired. am I ritght ?

Comment: Why are you setting `async: false` if you're using callbacks? Also, are you sure that `data` is truly `"false"` and that the callback is actually running?

Comment: Show us what value it had before and how you are checking that it was changed. And are you really expecting `"\"false\""` as a response? Show us that, and make sure that the if-statement in the success callback was actually evaluated.

Comment: async is set to false beacuse I re-used the code from another call. Its true, it doesnt need to be setted to false if I use callbacks. That callback is triggered and the returned value inside data is "true" or "false, so it works.


Bergi: after the code I posted is a 

              console.log(info_estancia[0]['foto']);

to see the current value of the variable and when the callback is triggered and the data == "false" it keeps the old value and not the null I try to set in the callback

Comment: Did you also log `data`? And try a `console.log(typeof data)`, what will it yield?

Comment: @AlbertPrats: Are you sure that the `if` statement's condition is actually true?

Answer (score -1):

Assign what you want to access to a variable before the definition of your callback function.

```
var reference = get_info_estancia(); //or access it how you like
resultatAJAX.success(function(data) {               
        if (data == "false") {
          reference[0]['foto'] = "null";
        }
      });
```

Comment: What difference would that make? Please explain how the change could help.

Comment: Perhaps his namespace is getting messed up and the info_estancia inside the callback is not referring to the one he wants.